# Showing Differentiability of Function

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Prove that $$f(t) = \int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(tx)}{1+x^{2}} dx $$ is differentiable on $(0, \infty)$.

I tried to use dominated convergence theorem but have trouble finding the dominating function.... If we take the derivative $\frac{d}{dt}$ inside the integral, we get $$f_{t}(x) = \frac{x \cos(tx)}{1+x^{2}}$$ inside the integral, but I don't see how I can use the theorem here...

Comment: the differentiated integrand is difficult to handle. If you make the transformation $tx= y$ you get an integral which looks more complicated at first sight, but should be easier to treat wrt to $t$ differentiability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you don't want to calculate the integral but are only interested in differentiability you can change variables, $y:=tx$. This results in
$$\int\limits_t^\infty\frac{\sin(y)}{1+\frac{y^2}{t^2}}\frac{1}{t}dy
= t\int\limits_t^\infty\frac{\sin(y)}{t^2+y^2}dy
  $$

This can now rather easy be formally differentiated using Leibnitz' rule and the chain rule and the result is also easily seen to be integrable.